# SharePoint masterpage footer always showing in Search Results preview

Tags: search, search-results, master-page

I have a footer in my masterpage. It contains some CQWP and some static links that is present all throughout my site.

The weird thing is, whenever I search, the footer data is always shown in the search results page. I'm thinking it is getting crawled somehow?

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We want to exclude the contact us and privacy policy links in the navigation from our search results.  How do we do that?  It’s pretty simple actually.  Just put the content that you do not want indexed in a div tag with a class of `noindex`.

Let’s look at the complete HTML of the home page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Super Neat Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Welcome to our awesome site. We are the best! <a href="test.html">Awesome Stuff</a>
        If you need to get a hold of us, click <a href="contactus.html">here</a>. Worried,
        we'll <a href="privacy.html">sell you out?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="noindex">
        <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a> <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that the Contact Us and Privacy Policy links are inside `<div class="noindex">`.  You might have noticed that the body of the page also has links to these two pages.  I had to include these so that those pages would get indexed.  Since the common navigation is excluded there was no way for the crawler to follow those links.  This is something you will want to consider when you are designing master pages because you will need to have at least one link to each page on the site somewhere.

Since I learned about this in the context of FAST Search for SharePoint, I decided to look at it first.  The first thing I will do is show you the results of the entire content source.  That way you will believe me that all of the pages are in the index. :)

Happy Coding:)

**@dipshare1**